# HTML button with Jquery Under CDATA

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, xml, cdata

I was wondering how would I implement javascript/jquery and html in the CDATA section of an XML. Im trying to create a gmail contextual gadget and this is the first time I had to deal with CDATA section in XML.

Basically I want to create a simple button when clicked will display a hello world perhaps.

*EDIT*

I found out that there is some extensive documentation on what I wanted to accomplish http://code.google.com/apis/gadgets/docs/ui.html

Comment: You should post your edit as an answer...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://code.google.com/apis/gadgets/docs/ui.html